# Switching content presenter on property, passing full data context to children?

Tags: wpf

I have the following view.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type search:SomeChildType1Vm}">
      <a:SomeParentType1 DataContext="{Binding}" />
   </DataTemplate>

   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type search:SomeChildType2Vm}">
      <a:SomeParentType2 DataContext="{Binding}" />
   </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{Binding SomeChildTypeProperty}" />
</Grid>
```

My datacontext for the view is a class like the following:

```
public class MySpecialVm
{
    public SomeChildType SomeChildTypeProperty {get;set;}
}

public class SomeChildType1 : SomeChildType
{
...
}

public class SomeChildType2 : SomeChildType
{
...
}

public class SomeChildType
{
...
}
```

I'd like to have the type of the SomeChildTypeProperty property control which control is displayed by the content presenter.

Is this possible? In the current format, the datacontext which gets passed to the controls is always of SomeChildType1 or SomeChildType2, which is not ideal as you can imagine. :)

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding}"` is redundant. The DataTemplate's children will already inherit the DataTemplate's DataContext. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, after submitting the question I found the solution.

Using the code sample provided at https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/, I was able to produce the following.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <valueConverters:NullableObjectToTypeConverter
      x:Key="NullableObjectToTypeConverter" />

   <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeParentType1Template" DataType="{x:Type a:SomeParentType}">
      <a:SomeParentType1Control DataContext="{Binding}" />
   </DataTemplate>

   <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeParentType2Template" DataType="{x:Type a:SomeParentType}">
      <a:SomeParentType2Control DataContext="{Binding}" />
   </DataTemplate>

   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type a:SomeParentType}">
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding }">
         <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
               <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                       Value="{StaticResource SomeParentType1Template}" />
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger
                     Binding="{Binding SomeChildTypeProperty,
                     Converter={StaticResource NullableObjectToTypeConverter}}"
                     Value="{x:Type a:SomeChildType2}">
                     <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                             Value="{StaticResource SomeParentType2Template}" />
                  </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </ContentControl.Style>
      </ContentControl>
   </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                     Content="{Binding}" />
</Grid>
```

This also required an object to type converter.

```
public class NullableObjectToTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return value?.GetType();
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```